# Getting a partial value from a string in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, substring

Let's say I have a input box with the value of "foo_bar"

I want to assign foo to a variable, as well as bar. I never know the lengths of each of those. Essentially, anything to the left of the _ should be one variable, and everything to the right should be another.

How would you do this in jQuery?

Comment: var str = "foo_bar", my_arr = str.split(/_/);

Comment: String manipulation is done with [standard JS String methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/#Methods_2) (which is - I assume - why jQuery doesn't provide methods to do it).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jQuery for that, you can do it in plain JavaScript. A regular expression is one alternative, or if you know that you'll always have the '_' separator, you can use the `indexOf` method to find its position and split from there.

Or with an example:

```
var val = $("#inputId").val();
int separatorIndex = val.indexOf('_');
var first = val.substring(0, separatorIndex);
var second = val.substring(separatorIndex + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this code:

```
var str = "foo_bar"; // Change with input data
var index = str.indexOf("_");
if (index < 0) return false; // Change this with your '_' not found code
var foo = str.substr(0, index);
var bar = str.substr(index + 1);
```

Comment: you do not check the situation when `index` var will equal `-1`

Comment: He didn't ask for validation, but if it pleases you I added it. All he asked for is how to do it, and not how to validate if it's actually a properly formed string.

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = 'foo_bar'​;
​var b = a.split('_')​;

​var left = b[0]​;
var right = b[1​];
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of variety:

```
var
str = 'foo_bar',
left = /(.+)_/.exec(str)[1],
right = /_(.+)/.exec(str)[1]
```